# passing 'const Class2' as 'this' argument of 'int Class1::get_data()' discards qualifiers

Tags: c++, constructor, copy

I'm trying to set up a copy constructor and i'm getting this error

```
class Class1{
public:
    int get_data();
    void set_data(int);
private:
    int d;
};

int Class1::get_data(){
    return d;
}

void Class1::set_data(int data){
    d = data;
}

class Class2 : public Class1{
    Class2(const Class2&);
};

Class2::Class2(const Class2 &c2) : Class1(){
    set_data(c2.set_data());
}
```

whats a solution to this problem. i read some of the previous questions and i understand why this is happening. but making set_data() const is not an option.

whats the accepted approach for copy constructors?

thanks,

Comment: You aren't providing enough parameters to `c2.set_data()` in the body of `Class2`'s constructor. Also `set_data()` returns `void` so you can't use its "value" to pass to `set_data()`. The error message in the question title doesn't match the code that you have posted.

Answer (score 3):

You could just write a constructor for Class1 taking an int parameter:

```
class Class1 {
    explicit Class1 (int i) : d (i) {}
    // as before
};

class Class2 : public Class1 {
    Class2 (Class2 const & c2) : Class1 (c2.get_data ()) {}
};
```

However, the default copy constructor should be enought here (i.e. you don't need to write your own, the compiler will do it for you).

Generally speaking, you should use initialisation lists:

http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors.html

in the constructors (read the whole entry in the faq)

Edit: You forgot the 'const' qualifier for your get_data function.

Answer (score 0):

Don't you want:

```
set_data(c2.get_data());
```

(and make the `Class1::get_data()` member function `const`)?

But you really should be using constructor initialization lists:

```
Class2::Class2(const Class2 &c2)
    : Class1(c2)
{
}
```

This code uses the compiler-generated default copy constructor for `Class1`. In many cases you shouldn't use the default copy constructor or copy-assign operator overload, but here it's fine because the sole data member of `Class1` is an `int` object.

In fact, you could even rely on the compiler-generated default copy constructor for `Class2`.

**EDIT:** Here is some example code:

```
#include <iostream>

class Class1{
public:
    Class1() : d(0) { } // Provide a no-arg constructor to initialize `d`

    int get_data() const; // Class1::get_data() is `const` because it does not change the `Class1` object.
    void set_data(int);
private:
    int d;
};

int Class1::get_data() const{
    return d;
}

void Class1::set_data(int data){
    d = data;
}

class Class2 : public Class1{
public:
    Class2();
};

Class2::Class2()
    : Class1()
{
}

int main() {
    Class2 other_c2;
    other_c2.set_data(14);
    Class2 c2(other_c2);
    std::cout << c2.get_data() << '\n';
}
```

http://codepad.org/jlplTYrH